# Create default Rails model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, new-operator

Is there a way to set up a Rails model to have default associations to existing resources, i.e. I create a new blog post and it automatically gets assigned author with id 10.

Comment: Do you _always_ want the default association to point to user with id 10?

Comment: Possibly, please let me know what you suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this in your BlogPost model, this would assign user 10 with every blog post that's created.

```
after_create do |blog_post|
  blog_post.user = User.find(10)
  blog_post.tags = Tag.all  # Or whatever
end
```

Edit:

To have this happen when you call new use the after_initialize callback instead:

```
after_initialize do |blog_post|
  blog_post.user = User.find(10)
  blog_post.tags = Tag.all  # Or whatever
end
```

Comment: How would I change this so it assigned every tag (HABTM)? Plus, how would I make this take effect in the 'new' action?

Comment: Do you know how I could make this work so when new form is first rendered, the associations are already in place? (it's for a nested form)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is what you're getting at but you can achieve what you want to do by using the association extensions that come with active record i.e.

```
u = User.first
u.blog_posts.create(:title => 'great post', :content => 'better content')
```

This will create a blog post and automatically assign the user_id to that of user u

See this page for more information: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I'm looking to link it to existing resources, e.g. a new blog post is automatically associated with all tags